# Bivariate normal expectation of the sinus cardinal

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, bivariate

I would like to get an analytical expression for
$$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\sin(aX)}{aX}\frac{\sin(bY)}{bY}\right)$$
or at least an analytical approximation thereof, when $a,b$ are positive reals, and

$$\begin{pmatrix}X\\Y\end{pmatrix} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma) $$
where

$$\mu \equiv \begin{pmatrix}x^\circ \\ y^\circ\end{pmatrix}
\quad \Sigma \equiv \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \rho \\ \rho & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Using either the probability density function or the characteristic function to compute the expectation leads me to an expression with a single integral, but I can't go further than this.

Comment: Do you need an exact (analytical) solution (not saying that it's possible at all), or will a numerical approximation do? If numerical works: just sample 10000 values for X and Y and calculate the mean of your expression of interest over your samples...

Comment: yes, corrected.

Comment: @yannick: Is this homework? If so please add the homework tag. Hint: you can integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x}dx$ by writing the [power series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Examples) expansion of $\sin x$ and integrating by parts. Doing this should give you $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x}dx=\pi$.

Comment: no it's not homework, it's just work :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's some R code that does a numerical approximation (I assume it is clear how to change this for other values of the parameters):

```
require(MASS)
n<-10000
mux<-0
muy<-0
rho<-0.5
sig<-matrix(c(1,rho,rho,1), ncol=2)
dta<-mvrnorm(n = n, mu=c(mux, muy), Sigma=sig)

a<-1
b<- -1

appr<-mean(sin(a*dta[,1])/(a*dta[,1]) * sin(b*dta[,2])/(b*dta[,2]))
appr
```

Comment: I meant that I needed an analytical form, nor numerical. sorry.

Comment: @NickSabbe When posting code, please state what software is being used. Thanks.